# How to show homomorphism of this mapping?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $ M_{2 \times 2} ( \mathbb{R} )$ be the $ \mathbb{R}$- Algebra  of all the $ 2 \times 2$- matrices with coefficients in $ \mathbb{R}$ and $ \mathbb{R}[X] $ the polynomial ring over $\mathbb{R}$ and 
 If $ \mathbf{A} \in M_{2 \times 2} (\mathbb{R})$ then show that the map

$ \phi : \mathbb{R}[X] \to M_{2 \times 2} (\mathbb{R})$ defined as

$ \sum_{i=0}^d r_i X^i  \rightarrow \sum_{i=o}^d r_i \mathbf{A}^i  $ is a homomorphism of $\mathbb{R} $- algebras ?

Comment: You can think of this as an  "evaluation" homomorphism, where $X$ acts on $V$ (in this case $\mathbb R^2$ by some endomorphism (which is a two by two matrix.) There is only one nonotrivial thing to verify, given in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show an $\mathbb{R}$ algebra homomorphism you need to show that 
$ \forall k\in \mathbb{R}$ and $p(X),q(X) \in \mathbb{R}[X]$

A) $\phi(k\cdot p(X)) = k\phi(p(X))$

B)$\phi(p(X)+q(X)) = \phi(p(X)) + \phi(q(X))$

C)$\phi(p(X) \cdot q(X)) = \phi(p(X))\cdot\phi(q(X))$

Conditions A and B are quite easy to prove and are almost immediate, for condition C you need to multiply $p(X)$ and $q(X)$ and take care of the indices. Then you will get the result instantly. Try this, if you need help then comment below.

Comment: thank you ! i got a bit confused by several definitions. But i should handle that from here :)

Comment: Yeah, I got the drift because this is a very easy question and realized that you probably need to know what is a R-algebra homomorphism :)

Comment: one more question..if $ A= \begin{pmatrix} 0 $ 1 \\  -1 $ 0\end{matrix} $. I cant determine the nernel of $ \phi $ ? Because the determinant is not zero, right?

Comment: If, I understand correctly you want to find out $\phi^{-}(0)$. Say for $p(X), \phi(p(X)=0$. So, you get a polynomial satisfied by $A$ that is zero. To find such a polynomial you use the cayley-hamilton theorem. Are you aware of it?

Comment: i mean $ A= \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} $ and yes, i also mean the kernel :)

Comment: Why can't you find the kernel? look at $det(A - X*I)$. Here that will be $X^2 + 1$. Any polynomials with this as a factor will map to $0$ under $\phi$